# Enable Button only when 2 TextInput fields are not empty - code and screenshot attached

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6, flex-mobile

In a Flex mobile app (or any Flex 4 application) - how can you enable/disable a button depending on the contents of 2 other fields?

[image]

I am pasting my very simple test code below and the problem with it is the syntax error in Flash Builder 4.7: `The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.` - which probably means that ampersand is a special character, but how to solve this (probably frequent) problem?

**TestApp.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    firstView="views.Home" 
    applicationDPI="160">
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

**views/Home.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        title="How to enable Login button?">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="8"
            horizontalAlign="center" gap="8" />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Label text="Username:" />
    <s:TextInput id="_username" />
    <s:Label text="Password:" />
    <s:TextInput id="_password" />

    <s:Button id="_login" 
              label="Login" 
              enabled="{_username.text.length > 0 && _password.text.length > 0}" />
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shall replace `&&` with `&amp;&amp;` when you write it outside of CDATA in mxml.

It is also better to use `_username.text!=''` instead of `_username.text.length > 0` because it will cause warnings at runtime as `text` is not an eventdispatcher and it can't report `length` changes. However, it will update button's availablity because `text` will be changed itself and `TextInput` will report it causing binding update.

Answer (score 0):

when using binding expressions. mxml does not consider && rather write your expression as

> & amp ; & amp ;

....also mxml does not read escape characters e.g. \t for tab...rather write your expression in actionscript then use data binding .cheers ;-)